# How do I specify a one to one relationship in Entity Framework Core where both sides have a foreign key to each other?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

All the documentation I'm finding on one to one relationships in Entity Framework talk about one side being the dependent and only having a foreign key in one table. How can I tell Entity Framework that both tables have a foreign key to each other. Here is a simple example:

```
public class TechnicalAdvisor
{
  public Guid TechnicalAdvisorId { get; set; }
  public Guid ProjectRequestId { get; set; }
  public virtual ProjectRequest ProjectRequest { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRequest 
{
  public Guid ProjectRequestId { get; set; }
  public Guid? TechnicalReviewCompletedById { get; set; }
  public virtual TechnicalAdvisor TechnicalReviewCompletedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The use case is we have a project request that requires technical review. The `TechnicalAdvisor` table is a whitelist basically for who can do it. Then we need an id for who actually did it. I can't figure out how to tell Entity Framework what this relationship is.

Comment: I would have expected a 1:M or M:N relationship. Can't a Technical Advisor review more than one Project in their lifetime? Does every project have a single technical advisor?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need an additional table to represent the `TechincalAdvisor`s who are on the `Whitelist`.

```
public class TechnicalAdvisorWhitelist
{
  public int Id {get; set;} 
  public Guid TechnicalAdvisorId  {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was seeing this wrong. Really I had two relationships: 1:0/1 and 1:many so really the answer is this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TechnicalAdvisor>()
            .HasOne(x => x.ProjectRequest)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("ProjectRequestId");

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectRequest>()
            .HasOne(x => x.TechnicalReviewCompletedBy)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<ProjectRequest>(x => x.TechnicalReviewCompletedById);
```

Comment: This looks like regular one to many relationship. One doesn't have to define foreign key IDs when there's no need for manual mapping and I don't see a need for that here. Just reference TechnicalAdvisor in ProjectRequest and if you want to be able to query ProjectRequests eg reviewed by TechnicalAdvisor from  TechnicalAdvisor class, define a collection ICollection<ProjectRequest> ReviewedProjectRequests inside of it.

Comment: Btw, what I said about no need to manually define FKs, it was in the context of 1:n and using convention. However EF Core requires manually defined FK on one side of 1:1 relation (when convention is used) I think.